# how to add font in DreamWeaver CC for coding?

Tags: fonts, dreamweaver

I want add one custom font in `DreamWeaver CC` for coding but I don't know about it.
please guide me and tell me that how add one font in this program and use for coding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it :

1. Select Edit | Preferences to bring up the Preferences dialog box.
2. From the Category column, select Fonts.
3. Under the Fonts section from the Font settings list, select the Proportional font, Fixed font, and/or Code view using the pull-down lists to select the desired font and size.
4. Click OK.